# If the series converges absolutely, the value of absolutely convergence and of convergence are same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the series converges absolutely, the values of absolutely convergence and of convergence are same?

Im sorry for the grammar mistake. Im studying English but it is a little difficult. ಥ‿ಥ

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are the values of absolutely convergence and of convergence of a series?

Comment: Thanks! The value of absolutely convergence what i said means that ,in 1st answer, "2", and the value of convergence means that "2/3".

Comment: If you mean does $\sum a_n$ equal $\sum|a_n|$ then the answer is no, they are not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n$$

converges absolutely

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=2$$

by summing the geometric series, but

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n=\frac{2}{3}$$

Absolute convergence tells you that the series converges, but not what it converges to.

Comment: Wow thanks for the absolute couterexample!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as

$$\left|\sum_k a_k \right| \leq \sum_k |a_k|$$

you can see that absolute convergence implies normal convergence, and give also a bound on the limit. But there is no clue that they converge to the same value, as pointed out by @Aidan.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I got it :)